# How to setup Jest Watch Plugins with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Would like to implement some "hooks"/[jest plugins](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/watch-plugins) to the tests I make with create-react-app.

Created an PoC app `npx create-react-app jest-watch-plugins` with this in the root

**./yourWatchPlugin.js**

```
class MyWatchPlugin {
  apply(jestHooks) {
    jestHooks.onTestRunComplete(results => {
      console.log('Hello watcher')
    })
  }
}
```

**./jest.config.js**

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  watchPlugins: ['./yourWatchPlugin'],
}
```

Then I did `yarn test` and saw no nothing being logged.

Then I tried

**./package.json**

```
{
  "name": "jest-watch-plugins",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "jest": {
    "watchPlugins": [
      "./yourWatchPlugin"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

But it throws this at me:

```
$ yarn test 
yarn run v1.17.3
$ react-scripts test

Out of the box, Create React App only supports overriding these Jest options:

  • collectCoverageFrom
  • coverageReporters
  • coverageThreshold
  • coveragePathIgnorePatterns
  • extraGlobals
  • globalSetup
  • globalTeardown
  • moduleNameMapper
  • resetMocks
  • resetModules
  • snapshotSerializers
  • transform
  • transformIgnorePatterns
  • watchPathIgnorePatterns.

These options in your package.json Jest configuration are not currently supported by Create React App:

  • watchPlugins

If you wish to override other Jest options, you need to eject from the default setup. You can do so by running npm run eject but remember that this is a one-way operation. You may also file an issue with Create React App to discuss supporting more options out of the box.

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Any pointer in the right direction will be appreciated.

### Update

I have tried this

```
{
  "name": "jest-watch-plugins",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "jest": {
    "watchPlugins": [
      "./yourWatchPlugin"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.jsx?$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg|css|less|scss)$": "<rootDir>/__jest__/fileMock.js"
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

but it throws

```
$ yarn test                                                                                             Lasse Norfeldt
yarn run v1.17.3
$ ./node_modules/.bin/jest
 FAIL  src/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    SyntaxError: /Users/norfeldt/Learning/Playgrounds/Jest/jest-watch-plugins/src/App.test.js: Unexpected token (7:18)

       5 | it('renders without crashing', () => {
       6 |   const div = document.createElement('div');
    >  7 |   ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
         |                   ^
       8 |   ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
       9 | });
      10 | 

      at Parser.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6325:17)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.073s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json scripts use:

`"test": "./../../node_modules/.bin/jest",`

This will run the Jest binary directly and let you use any config that you like

If you go this route you will need to add some things to your jest config in the package.json like:

```
  "jest": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.jsx?$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg|css|less|scss)$": "<rootDir>/__jest__/fileMock.js"
    }
  },
```

Comment: If i do `"test": "./node_modules/.bin/jest",` I get `Jest encountered an unexpected token`

Comment: yeah one of the cons of this approach is that you will have to supply your own config to tell Jest which files to ignore and which to use. What kind of file did it complain about? If .js add babel-jest to your jest config in your package.json https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-jest

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help. I did as you suggested (see update question)

Comment: apologies - I grabbed that from a Typescript project. Try `"transform": {"^.+\\.[t|j]sx?$": "babel-jest"},` .The current setup will only transform files with a .tsx extension

Answer (score -4):

Jest comes with default watcher, you have to configure it.

Comment: A little more instructions would be appreciated 

Comment: Sure, I will. :)